AWS event-bridge is not invoked the AWS lambda function
I am creating new lambda function using nodejs aws-sdk. It's successfully creating new lambda function.
const createLambdaFunction = async (params) => {
try {
    const createFunctionParams = {
        FunctionName: params.functionName,
        Role: params.functionRole,
        Handler: params.handler,
        Runtime: params.runtime,
        Description: params.description,
        Timeout: params.timeout,
        MemorySize: params.memorySize,
        Code: {
            ZipFile: require('fs').readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'test-function.zip'))
        },
        Environment: {
            Variables: {
                send_grid_api_key: process.env.SEND_GRID_API_KEY
            }
        }
    };
    const createFunctionResponse = await lambda.createFunction(createFunctionParams).promise();

    const addPermissionParams = {
        Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
        FunctionName: params.functionName,
        Principal: 'events.amazonaws.com',
        SourceArn: params.functionRole,
        StatementId: 'EventBridgeInvokePermission',
    };
    await lambda.addPermission(addPermissionParams).promise();

    console.log('Lambda function created successfully with CRON expression trigger:', createFunctionResponse);
    return createFunctionResponse;
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating Lambda function:', error);
    throw error;
}};

After I am creating new event-bride cron to invoke lambda function on every 5 minute using same node aws-sdk. Also I added lambda function as a target in this event-bride rule.
async function createEventBridgeRule({ ruleName, lambdaArn, cronExpression, eventPayload }) {
try {
    const params = {
        Name: ruleName,
        ScheduleExpression: cronExpression,
        State: 'ENABLED',
    };

    const result = await eventBridge.putRule(params).promise();
    console.log('EventBridge rule created successfully', result);

    const putTargetsParams = {
        Rule: ruleName,
        Targets: [
            {
                Arn: lambdaArn,
                Id: '1',
                Input: JSON.stringify(eventPayload)
            }
        ]
    };
    
    await eventBridge.putTargets(putTargetsParams).promise();
    console.log('Lambda function added as target successfully.');
    return result;
} catch (err) {
    console.error('Error creating EventBridge rule:', err);
    throw err;
}}

But still it's not calling lambda function on 5 minute time interval. I have to add trigger manuaaly in lambda function from console to invoke the function.
HOW CAN I DO IT USING NODE AWS-SDK?

If you add a dead-letter queue to your target (EventBridge rule) you should see IAM issues because this seems wrong SourceArn: params.functionRole: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-use-resource-based.html#eb-lambda-permissions
Btw: please consider using our new Scheduler service: https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/scheduler/?nc1=h_ls
